How to track or view logs of emails sent by Azure Logic App?
I have a logic app on Azure which sends emails via the task "Send an Email (V2)" using an Outlook 365 connector. How do I see the logs of emails sent and their details (ie address, subject, body, time sent)?
Note I do not have access to the email address which is used to send out the emails

You will not get logs of details inside each step of logic app, but you can track them if you added in tracked properties, If you want to know about that, I can give you that

@RithwikBojja please do :)

By default, such details from Logic App triggers or actions are not logged - unless you specify custom tracked properties in the settings of the relevant action.
For the Send an email (V2) action, the custom properties can be set up as follows:



Name
Value




To
@action()['inputs']['body']['To']


Subject
@action()['inputs']['body']['Subject']


Body
@slice(action()['inputs']['body']['Body'], 0, 8000)




These details will be logged in the AzureDiagnostics table (for Consumption Logic Apps) or in the LogicAppWorkflowRuntime table (for Standard Logic Apps).
Testing:

Result:

